# Summing a list of floats:TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, list, math, sum, sequence

so the problem is that I keep getting this error message:

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

```
range_list = range(1, 97)


for p in range_list:

    p_numerator = 4*((-1)**(p+1))
    p_denominator = 2*p - 1

    function_ofK = float(p_numerator)/float(p_denominator)


    total = sum(function_ofK)
    print(total)
```

Here is the problem I need to solve:

[Problem:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3yPA.png)

Comment: your function_ofK isn't a list right now. i would expect you getting complaints about float objects instead of an int object though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always remember that **sum()** function takes a list of values (iterable). In your case, you are just passing a float. A little help on its usage can be gotten from Python interactive terminal as follows.

```
Rishikeshs-MacBook-Air:Try hygull$ python3
Python 3.6.7 (v3.6.7:6ec5cf24b7, Oct 20 2018, 03:02:14) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> help(sum)

Help on built-in function sum in module builtins:

sum(iterable, start=0, /)
    Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers

    When the iterable is empty, return the start value.
    This function is intended specifically for use with numeric values and may
    reject non-numeric types.
```

Now, you can try like this.

## `Using sum()`

```
range_list = range(1, 97)
values = []

for p in range_list:
    p_numerator = 4*((-1)**(p+1))
    p_denominator = 2*p - 1

    function_ofK = float(p_numerator)/float(p_denominator)

    values.append(function_ofK)

total = sum(values)
print(total) # 3.131176269454982
```

## `Without using sum()`

```
range_list = range(1, 97)
total = 0

for p in range_list:
    p_numerator = 4*((-1)**(p+1))
    p_denominator = 2*p - 1

    function_ofK = float(p_numerator)/float(p_denominator)

    total += function_ofK

print(total) # 3.131176269454982
```

### `You should try`

```
def get_sum(start, end):
    range_list = range(start, end + 1)
    total = 0

    for p in range_list:
        p_numerator = 4*((-1)**(p+1))
        p_denominator = 2*p - 1

        function_ofK = float(p_numerator) / float(p_denominator)

        total += function_ofK

    return total
```

Now you just call that function and get your work done.

```
total = get_sum(1, 96)
print(total) # 3.131176269454982

total = get_sum(1, 100)
print(total) # 3.1315929035585537
```

Answer (score 0):

`function_ofK` is a `float`. `sum` function needs a `list` (more specifically an `iterable`)
This is what you might need to do.

```py
range_list = range(1, 97)
function_ofK = []

for p in range_list:
    p_numerator = 4*((-1)**(p+1))
    p_denominator = 2*p - 1

    function_ofK.append(p_numerator/p_denominator)

# the total is out of for loop
total = sum(function_ofK)
print(total) # 3.131176269454982
```